# tensorflow import error in python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, python-import

I have installed tensor flow from [tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#TF_PYTHON_URL). While trying to import tensor flow its showing following error

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line  24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/__init__.py",   line 37, in <module>
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",   line 36, in <module>
import email.parser
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from email.feedparser import FeedParser
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
from email import message
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
import email.charset
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/charset.py", line 13, in <module>
import email.base64mime
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
from email.utils import fix_eols
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 28, in <module>
import socket
File "/home/tamarind/socket.py", line 5, in <module>
This module provides socket operations and some related functions.
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I think its problem with socket please suggest. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `/home/tamarind/socket.py` is taking precedence over the python socket module. Just rename/remove that (or import TensorFlow from a different directory) and it should work. You may need to remove `socket.pyc` too.

Comment: Had to delete the file socket.py and socket.pyc and everything worked fine. Thanks!